# Complex conjugates

Tags: complex-numbers

If $z=e^{2 \pi i/5}$, so that $z=x+iy$ where $x=\cos(2\pi i/5)$ and $y=\sin(2\pi i/5)$, then how are $z$ and $z^4$ complex conjugates with each other? I see that visually, but $$z^4=x^4-6 x^2 y^2+y^4+i (4 x^3 y-4 x y^3)$$
and I'm not sure how this is equal to $z=x-iy$. Maybe I should use trigonometric identities?

Comment: Seeing visually seems nearly there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=e^{2\pi i/5}=\cos(2\pi /5)+i\sin(2\pi /5)$

$z^4=e^{8\pi i/5=}\cos(8\pi /5)+i\sin (8\pi /5)=\cos(2\pi -2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi-2\pi/5)=\cos(2\pi/5)-i\sin(2\pi/5)$

Answer (score 1):

Since $z^5=1$ we have $\overline{z}=z^{-1}=z^4$, as $z\overline{z}=|z|^2=1$. Similarly $\overline{z^4}=\overline{z^{-1}}=z$. In general, for an $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$ we have that $\zeta^{n-1}$ and $\zeta$ are conjugates of each other for this reason.

Answer (score 1):

$z^4=e^{8\pi i/5}=e^{(10-2)\pi i/5}=e^{2\pi i-2\pi i/5}=e^{2\pi i}\cdot e^{-2\pi i/5}=e^{-2\pi i/5}=\bar{z}$

Comment: How is this different from cello's answer...?

Comment: In no ways. We probably posted it at about the same time